# Java Optional: How to handle null with classes

Tags: java, option-type

I am trying with Optionals and I am pretty sure my solution is not good. I put a little sample below.

```
class Person {
    String name;    // can be null
    Integer age;    // can be null
}

class DB {
    // returns an Optional
    public static Optional<Person> getPerson() {
        //irrelevant code here
    }
}



public static void main() {
    Person p = DB.getPerson().orElse(null);

    // did I get a Person?
    if (p != null) {
        // both information of a Person available?
        if (p.name != null && p.age != null) {
            dosomthing (p.name, p.age);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to improve this? I see HERE no benefit in using Optionals. But I am not in charge of getPerson.

Comment: If you just call `getPerson()` without the orElse, you'll receive an `Optional<Person>`. Then you can check things like `p.isPresent()` instead of `p != null`. Although the example feels a little contrived

Comment: If a `Person`'s `name` and `age` cannot be `null`, can't you just make them non-nullable? If that's not possible, you could have `dosomthing` do the checks before running any operation.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't mean to make getName() and getAge() return Optional, as they are the things you indicate can be null?

Comment: If you are not in charge of getPerson, you can't really improve this... Ideally no person should have no name or age. `getPerson` should return an empty optional in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

So what about using Optional like this;

```
DB.getPerson()
        .filter(p -> p.name != null && p.age != null)
        .ifPresent(p -> dosomthing(p.name, p.age));
```

I assume you are using `Optional::ofNullable` in `getPerson()`

Comment: No need to do `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`. An `Optional` cannot contain null. It would just be empty.